# How to Find Max and Min values?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
main()
{
    int limit,input;
    int sum=0;
    int i;
    std::cout<<"Please Enter the limit: ";
    std::cin>>limit;
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"Please Input values: ";
        std::cin>>input;
        sum+=input;
    }
    std::cout<<"The sum of the values is: "<<sum;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"The average of the values is: "<<sum/1+i;


}
```

What to do if i want to find Max and Min Values from the values input by the user?

Comment: You forgot to give `main` a return type.

Comment: I know , i would right Int later but for now i dont know how to identify the max n min values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find largest and smallest number in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298906/find-largest-and-smallest-number-in-an-array)

Comment: Were you missing parenthesis to calculate the average? `sum/(1+i)`. Although, you could divide by `limit` and `i == limit` is true at that point so you certainly do not want the `+1` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the code below.

```
int main()
{
    int limit,input;
    int sum=0;
    int i;
    std::cout<<"Please Enter the limit: ";
    std::cin>>limit;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"Please Input values: ";
        std::cin>>input;

        if(i == 0)
        {
            min = input;
            max = input;
        }
        else
        {
            if(input < min)
                min = input;

            if(input > max)
                max = input;
        }
        sum+=input;
    }
    std::cout<<"The sum of the values is: "<<sum<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"The average of the values is: "<<sum/(1+i)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Max: "<<max<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Min: "<<min<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You Guys are amazing!!!! thank you so much for teaching  me a new skill!!! and thank you so much for making me thing the logic behind it!!! Also can you guys give me tips on how to become a better programmer?

Comment: Just practice and practice. And some C++ books for your reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
int min_v = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
int max_v = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
{
    std::cout<<"Please Input values: ";
    std::cin>>input;
    sum+=input;
    min_v = std::min(input, min_v);
    max_v = std::max(input, max_v);
}
```

Comment: All answers are correct but this on is more "C++-styled" :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways,
You can store all values input from user into a `std::vector<int>`.  Use this vector to find out sum of elements and then sort it using `std::sort` to get Max and Min values as well. Simple!

```
vector<int> v(limits);
for(int i = 0; i<limits; i++)
{
    int input;
    cin >> input;

    v.push_back(input);
}

int sum = 0;
for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
{
    sum += *it;
}

cout << "sum = " << sum << endl;


sort(v.begin(), v.end());

cout << "Min = " << v[0] << endl;
cout << "Max = " << v[v.size() -1] << endl;
```

Comment: `std::minmax_element` is better than `std::sort` for that.

Comment: And for the sum, `std::accumulate` may help.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I didn't knew about it. These functions seems quite cleaner than using loops.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to do the following:

1. Declare the variable to store `Max` and `Min` values.
2. Initialize `Min` with a very big value, e.g. 2147483647, and `Max` to a very small value, e.g. -2147483648.
3. Inside the loop, compare `input` with `Min`, if `input` is smaller than `Min`, update `Min`. Do the reverse with `Max`.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int max=0, min=0;
for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"Please Input values: ";
        std::cin>>input;
        sum+=input;

        if(i==0){
        max=input;
        min=input;
        }

        if(input>max)
          max=input;

        if(input<min)
          min=input;
    }

Now, you got the max and min value.
```